# How to test a TSQL stored procedure that updates a table (vs. returning a result set) using tSQLt

Tags: t-sql, testing, stored-procedures, tsqlt

Could tSQLt experts please chime in on the approach for testing a type of stored procedures that don't return anything, but perform field updates in a table? I understand how to test results **returned** from a function or an SP, but in case of an in-place update, how do I make the test run against a fake table vs. the actual table if the procedure has the table name hard-coded? The only way I can think of is to make the entire SP use dynamic SQL and pass the table name as a parameter, but that makes the code less readable and more brittle. Is there a better way? Below is a simple stored proc that looks at 2 other fields: TransactionDate and ENdOfDropDate, and sets the third field in the same table called "IsWithinAddDrop" to True or False depending on the outcome of the condition.

```
create table  tblT1
(
   ID [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
   TransactionDate   [datetime2](7) NULL,
   EndOfDropDate      [datetime2](7) NULL, 
   IsWithinAddDrop [nvarchar](10) NULL
)

insert into tblT1 (TransactionDate, EndOfDropDate) values ('1/1/2016',  '2/1/2016')
insert into tblT1 (TransactionDate, EndOfDropDate) values ('2/1/2016',  '1/2/2016')
insert into tblT1 (TransactionDate, EndOfDropDate) values ('3/1/2016',  '3/1/2016')

create procedure spUpdateIsWithinAddDrop
as 
begin
    Update t1
        set t1.IsWithinAddDrop =
        (case
            when t1.TransactionDate <= t1.EndOfDropDate then 'True'
            else 'False'
        end)
        from tblT1 t1
end

exec spUpdateIsWithinAddDrop
```

The result is the updated column IsWithinAddDrop in the table that I want to test:

```
TransactionDate EndOfDropDate   IsWithinAddDrop
2016-01-01      2016-02-01      True
2016-02-01      2016-01-02      False
2016-03-01      2016-03-01      True
```

Thanks!

Comment: Often the best way to test procedures like this is to make a smaller copy of your target table (t1) and set the procedure to execute over the copy. I have also seen this happen on much larger scales where an entire database will be created and populated in order to test a single batch job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is to start by mocking the table to isolate any dependencies (foreign keys etc.).  Then add enough data to test all the cases you want to cover (see comments in the example below) and use `tSQLt.AssertEqualsTable` to compare the contents of the target table with a pre-defined set of expected rows after running the procedure under test.

```
if schema_id(N'StackModuleTests') is null
    exec tSQLt.NewTestClass @ClassName = N'StackModuleTests'
go

if objectpropertyex(object_id(N'[StackModuleTests].[test spUpdateIsWithinAddDrop example]'), N'IsProcedure') = 1
    drop procedure [StackModuleTests].[test spUpdateIsWithinAddDrop example]
go

create procedure [StackModuleTests].[test spUpdateIsWithinAddDrop example]
as
begin
    --! Start by faking the table that will be updated to isolate this test from any other dependencies
    exec tSQLt.FakeTable @TableName = 'dbo.tblT1' ;

    --! We expect spUpdateIsWithinAddDrop to set IsWithinAddDrop to TRUE only if
    --! TransactionDate is less than or equal to EndOfDropDate so we need the
    --! following tests:
    --! 
    --! Positive case where TransactionDate equals EndOfDropDate
    --! Positive case where TransactionDate less than EndOfDropDate
    --! Negative case where TransactionDate more than EndOfDropDate
    --! May want other tests to cover scenarios where either column is null
    --! Purists would say that this should one unit test for each case, personally
    --! I feel that as SQL is a set based language it is OK to combine all cases
    --! into a single test (also minimises all the setup)
    --!

    --! Assemble the data required for all test cases
    insert into tblT1 (TransactionDate, EndOfDropDate)
    values
          ('20160101', '20160101')
        , ('20160101', '20160102')
        , ('20160102', '20160101') ;

    --! What do we expect to see afterwards?
    create table #expected
    (
      TransactionDate [datetime2](7) null
    , EndOfDropDate [datetime2](7) null
    , IsWithinAddDrop [nvarchar](10) null
    )

    insert into #expected (TransactionDate, EndOfDropDate, IsWithinAddDrop)
    values
          ('20160101', '20160101', 'True')
        , ('20160101', '20160102', 'True')
        , ('20160102', '20160101', 'False') ;

    --! Act
    exec dbo.spUpdateIsWithinAddDrop ;

    --! Assert that the contents of tblT1 now match the #expected contents
    --! Notice that we ignore the ID column completely in this test because
    --! it has nothing to do with the object under test (spUpdateIsWithinAddDrop)
    exec tSQLt.AssertEqualsTable @Expected = N'#expected', @Actual = N'tblT1' ;
end
go

exec tSQLt.Run '[StackModuleTests].[test spUpdateIsWithinAddDrop example]';
```

Hope this explains the approach sufficiently but if not please do seek further clarification.

Comment: Thank you, @datacentricity.
I came to a very similar solution after someone pointed me to this article   yesterday: http://theproactiveprogrammer.com/design/sql-unit-testing/
It's still a mystery to me how the table substitution happens in the test and why the procedure never updates the "real" table, but it works!

Comment: So what happens when you call tSQLt.FakeTable is that the real table gets re-named and a copy of the table is created using the real name.  The sproc doesn't realise this and quite happily runs against the fake table instead of the real one.  This all happens in the scope of a transaction which is automatically rolled back on conclusion of the test (regardless of outcome).  The really clever thing with FakeTable is that the mock table has no constraints (PK, UNQ, FK, CK etc) and all columns allow NULL which means that each test need only consider the table(s) and columns pertinent to the test

Comment: E.g. Picture an OrderDetail table, this has many NOT NULL columns as well as FKs to OrderHeader, Product etc.  The Product table might have FK's to Supplier, ProductType etc and OrderHeader might have FKs to Customer, SalesPerson etc.  Now imagine a sproc called OrderDetailUpdateStatus which has simple logic like "UPDATE OrderDetail SET StatusId = @NewStatusId WHERE OrderDetailId = @OrderDetail".  To write a test for this sproc you are only interested in the StatusId and OrderDetailId columns - you don't care about any of the other columns or indeed all the dependant tables.

Comment: Thank you for explaining. You just brought up an important point - if the real table gets renamed, does that mean other processes won't find it during the test execution? I.e. if I have a scheduled  job operating on that "real" table and I run 20-30 tests each taking a couple of seconds, it's conceivable the table will effectively disappear for a minute? What about views depending on it? Are they also going to break?
I was not going to run the testing framework in prod, but this makes it potentially "dangerous" to run even in a dev enviromnent, or am I missing something?

Comment: Anything outside of the test transaction that normally accesses the real table will be blocked by the open test transaction.  This leads me to a very important point.  You should never (I.e. NEVER) use tSQLt in a production environment.  tSQLt is a unit testing framework best used in a dedicated sandbox by developers or a dedicated build environment as part of a CI process.  You can use it in a shared dev environment but may still hit problems if multiple developers are running test suites at the same time.  I do everything in a sandbox and don't deploy tSQLt or unit tests even to shared DEV.

Comment: I would be surprised if each test took a few seconds.  We have almost 2,500 unit tests in our main DB - these complete in around 12 minutes on my dev VM sandbox (running in VMWare fusion on my macbbok pro)

Comment: Good point, indeed. Is it possible to isolate all tests in a separate DB? So if I have 5 DB's in my dev environment, each with their own schemas and a set of SP's, can I avoid installing tSQLt into every one of them and instead point to those schemas from another DB dedicated to testing, which has tSQLt installed in it, or does the framework have to be compiled into each DB being tested?

Comment: Unfortunately, tSQLt is designed to work within the context of the current database.  I don't see an issue with the tests residing in the same DB as the production code as long as there is a way to exclude or keep them separate when releasing to other environments. RedGate's SQL Compare has an option to exclude all tSQLt framework and tests (which is what we use).  Otherwise you could do something with SSDT - Ed Elliot has a good walk through of how to do this here: http://dataidols.com/blog/ssdt-tsqlt-a-serious-double-act-by-ed-elliott/